# Why does my formula fail when using strings to specify a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a visual basic macro to apply a formula for a number of cells. I want, essentially, to add each cell to each other cell, so if I have `A1=1`, `B1=2`, `C1=3`, `A2=4`,`B2=5`, and `C3=6`, and if I select these and then run the program, then I want `A3=A1+A2`, `B3=A1+B2`, `C3=A1+C2`.

The way that I've gone about this is by writing two for loops, and then inserting a function into a cell based on the current values of the loop variables. This all works fine. If insert a dummy function, for example, `"=A1+B1"` the sub functions as anticipated; however, if I insert a function based on the loop variables, the program throws application-defined or object-defined error.

If I'm misinterpreting the error's meaning or the source of the error, I apologize. The code in question, in case it helps, is below.

```
Sub Thing()
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Application.Selection
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
For r = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
    Set cRow = Rng.Rows(r)
    For c = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
        Dim col1 As String
        Dim col2 As String
        col1 = GetColumnName(cRow.Columns(c).Column)
            col2 = GetColumnName(cRow.Columns(1).Column)
            Cells(cRow.Row + ((r) * 1) + 3, cRow.Columns(c).Column).Formula = "=$" + col1 + " " + CStr(cRow.Row) + "+" + col2 + CStr(cRow.Row) + ""
    Next
Next
End Sub

Function GetColumnName(colNum As Integer) As String
Dim d As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim name As String
d = colNum 
name = ""
Do While (d > 0)
    m = (d - 1) Mod 26
    name = Chr(65 + m) + name
    d = Int((d - m) / 26)
Loop
GetColumnName = name
End Function
```

`col1` and `col2` are string defined by a Function I found and copied, named `GetColumnName`. `r` and `c` are the loop variables. `cRow` is defined by `Rng.Rows(r)` I can post more context if it's necessary, but I'm hoping it isn't.

I couldn't find a duplicate of this question, but I didn't really know what my question was, so I'm sorry if it is a duplicate.

Related, smaller, question: is there a way to get the in-office code editor to specify where in the line the error occurred? Java errors could be found by inserting meaningless whitespace until the line on which the error occurred referred to a very small bit of code: is there a similar trick for this?

Comment: Can you post a little more of your code, especially where you define the variables?  Also, what is the error you're getting?  Finally, if you have the VB Editor open, you can "walk" through the sub by pressing F8 - that often helps me determine where my bugs are, perhaps that can help?  If you get an error, you can press "Debug" which will take you to the line giving you the error.

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting to the output. They aren't adding the values of the column, they are just keeping `A1` - you can do this with a formula.

Comment: I added more of the program in (all of it), so you should be able to see the variable declarations. I think the problem is that something that I think is a string actually isn't, but I'm not sure that that's the problem. Also, the error is application-defined error or object-defined error - at least that's what the editor throws in the pop-up. Thanks for the step hint, but I actually knew that — I wanted to know if it was possible to locate within the line where the error occurs. Thanks anyway, though. Still a useful hint, but not necessary for such a simple program.

Comment: The above was in response to user3578951.





In response to Raystafarian's comment, I ought to have continued to series a bit more perhaps. It's meant to do that, and then on A4, A5, etc it's meant to be B1+A2, B1+B2, etc. Hopefully that clarifies my question a bit.

This is horribly formatted. I apologize. Shift+Enter apparently is ignored after posting.

Answer (score 0):

The code is failing with Run-time error 1004 Application Defined or Object Defined error on the line where you set add the formula to the cell:

```
Cells(cRow.Row + ((r) * 1) + 3, cRow.Columns(c).Column).Formula = "=$" + col1 + " " + CStr(cRow.Row) + "+" + col2 + CStr(cRow.Row) + ""
```

By stepping through the code, you can identify the line where it fails, but there isn't an easy way to identify which statement within the line produces the error. The best way to debug this issue is to write out the value of the Formula to check that it is valid:

```
Sub Thing()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Application.Selection
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer


    Dim curFormula As String

    For r = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
        Set cRow = Rng.Rows(r)
        For c = 1 To Rng.Columns.Count
            Dim col1 As String
            Dim col2 As String
            col1 = GetColumnName(cRow.Columns(c).Column)
            col2 = GetColumnName(cRow.Columns(1).Column)
            curFormula = "=$" + col1 + " " + CStr(cRow.Row) + "+" + col2 + CStr(cRow.Row) + ""
            Debug.Print curFormula
            Cells(cRow.Row + ((r) * 1) + 3, cRow.Columns(c).Column).formula = curFormula
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This gives the following output:
    =$B 5+B5

As you can see, there is a space in the formula, which is the cause of the issue. You'd need to change the following line:

```
curFormula = "=$" + col1 + " " + CStr(cRow.Row) + "+" + col2 + CStr(cRow.Row) + ""
```

to:

```
curFormula = "=$" + col1 + CStr(cRow.Row) + "+" + col2 + CStr(cRow.Row) + ""
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel stupid now for not spotting that. It's working now.

Comment: You're welcome. It can be hard to spot problems in VBA when you have a line with several different methods etc. I definitely recommend breaking down lines like that in to several shorter lines - it makes it much easier to debug (and also makes it easier to read and understand the code).